# "java/net/http/HttpClient" Error after compile and run

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm developin with Kotlin Multiplatform and Desktop Compose

Any idea why this happens?
When I run my app in the IDE (IntellijIDE) it runs perfectly fine, but after gradle createDistributable or any kind of compilation.

if I try to run it I get this error "java/net/http/HttpClient" I already tried different JDK(17, 18, 20, 21), different Kotlin(default and 1.9.20) versions and gradle (7.5.1 and 8.4).
It was working before, I haven't been able to pin point if it's something I added

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to launch your program using command line. It should print more details about the error. It might help you solve the problem. If not, paste the error stack-trace in your question. Without it, it is difficult to know what is the problem.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, do NOT use `exception.message` as an error message. The exception type is part of the message.

Comment: without more context it's hard to tell what you mean by "I'm developing with Kotlin Multiplatform" but if you want to run your code on non-JVM platforms it can obviously not be using anything from the Java stdlib. Not sure if this error is in any way related to this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that HttpClient was still being called despite my switch to OkHttp. If you're utilizing HttpClient within Desktop's Compose, this issue may arise. Ensure you're using OkHttp instead, as it currently proves effective for API function calls. In my case, I had to recreate everything. Clearing the cache might have resolved the issue, even after changing the HTTP tool.